# Redirect an array of URLs in Express JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

I want to assign an array of URLs from a React app (using Express server side rendering) and assign 301 redirects to each URL.

The slug/id format is changing and I need a way to ensure old links already indexed by Google our saved in the wild have a way to find their way to the new URL format.

This function will be a one-time use, as new URLs will follow the new slug/id format, but the redirects need to remain so that they can continue their redirects.

I know how to assign a single redirect to one URL using `res.redirect` but not an entire array.

(This is my first SO post. Tried to explain this as well as I can but apologies if there are gaps).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to create `router.get` functions, so something like:

```js
const urls = ['/url1', '/url2', '/url3'];

urls.forEach(url => {
    router.get(url, (req, res, next) => {
        res.redirect(301, '/redirected-route');
    })
)};
```

If they all need to go to different URLs rather than all to the same one, then you can define the redirect array as an array of objects with `oldUrl`, and `newUrl` properties to create a more dynamic redirect.

```js
const urls = [
    { oldUrl: '/url1', newUrl: '/new-url1' },
    { oldUrl: '/url2', newUrl: '/new-url2' },
    { oldUrl: '/url3', newUrl: '/new-url3' }
];


urls.forEach(url => {
    router.get(url.oldUrl, (req, res, next) => {
        res.redirect(301, url.newUrl);
    })
)};
```